# Re-position Logo in Firebase AuthUI

Tags: android, firebase, firebaseui

Is there a way to re-position the app logo on the FirebaseAuthUI sign-in screen so that it is not near the top? I'm only using buttons for two of the available sign-up methods and it leaves a lot of space in between the logo and the buttons.